# Where is the default output folder for dotnet restore?

Tags: .net-core

I tried to create a simple .net core using commandline

```
dotnew new
```

in a certain folder called netcoreExample and I could see that there are two files created which are program.cs and project.json. Then I add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to dependencies entry in project.json

When I try to run the command

```
dotnet restore
```

it shows the package is restores successfully. However, when I inspect the folder where I run dotnet restore from, I didn't see the "packages" folder which is usually created when with the old C# projects running Nuget restore.

I wonder where the dotnet restore output all of the dependencies to.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On Windows by default its `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`. I wish `dotnet restore -verbosity <verbosity-level>` printed out where it was restoring to.

On other OSes its like `<HOME-environment-variable-location>/.nuget/packages`

Comment: FYI use --packages option to specify a custom output folder.

Comment: "I wish dotnet restore -verbosity <verbosity-level> printed out where it was restoring to" +1 to that

Comment: `<HOME-environment-variable-location>` is usually denoted `~`. :-)